# Understanding the add command on dockerfile for Ubuntu

Tags: docker

Does `ADD` command copy my directory files (including sub-directories files) into a new destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will, assuming `<src>` is a directory in `ADD <src> <dest>`.

The [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) command is a bit tricky but mostly for the `<dest>` part. For instance, the `ADD` command behaves differently depending on when `<dest>` ends with a slash or not.

Comment: What happen if I want to copy or add just a specific files? You know how to do that or you know some references?